# Unsaved changes of object in EditPage are unintentionally passed back to ListPage upon navigating back in .net MAUI

Tags: data-binding, maui

I have a .net MAUI Shell application with a page (ListPage) that displays a CollectionView of objects. The ItemsSource of this CollectionView is a cached list of objects which is backed by a SQLite store that is synced to an Azure SQL database.

Upon tapping an item in the CollectionView, a bottom sheet is opened with extra information of that object. This is handled through the SelectedItem property of the CollectionView. The bottom sheet has a button to edit the object which calls Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(Editpage), objectparameters). The object is then retrieved by the EditPage through ApplyQueryAttributes. Any changes made in the EditPage can be saved by a SaveButton. Tapping the SaveButton sends a Message through the WeakReferenceMessenger to the ListPage which adds/edits the object and updates the CollectionView. This works all fine so far.

However, when I edit any of the object's properties (name, date...) but do not tap the save button but simply navigate back by calling Shell.Current.GoToAsync(".."), the changes made in the EditPage are also displayed in my BottomSheet of ListPage despite not saving them. It seems that the object is somehow stored but I don't know how. Also, when refreshing the cached items of the ListPage, the unsaved changes made in the EditPage are also reflected in the CollectionView. Only upon syncing with the SQLite store, the unsaved changes are discarded and the original values seen in the ListPage and EditPage.

Any help with this?

ListPage

```cs
async Task Edit(object item)
{
    try
    {
        if (item is SurgicalActivity)
        {
            var activity = item as SurgicalActivity;
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ClinicalActivityEditPage)}",
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "activity", activity }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<CollectionView x:Name="ActivityCollection" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedActivities}" Margin="0,20,0,0" 
                                            SelectionMode="Single" 
                                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"                       
                                            SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged"
                                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"  
                                            IsGrouped="True"
                                            MinimumHeightRequest="100">

    <BoxView 
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        BackgroundColor="#4B000000"                  
        x:Name="Backdrop"
        IsEnabled="False"
        IsVisible="False"
        Opacity="0"
        InputTransparent="False"                                 
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
        <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
        </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
    </BoxView>

    <Border x:Name="BottomToolbar"
            BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" 
            TranslationY="450"
            Grid.Row="1"       
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20"
            Stroke="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}"
            Margin="-2">
        <Border.GestureRecognizers>
            <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Down" Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped"/>
        </Border.GestureRecognizers>
        <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,0.65" Margin="20">
                <BoxView Color="White" HeightRequest="5" WidthRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                         CornerRadius="30" Margin="0,0,0,20"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding SelectedItem.MainProcedure}"
                       TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="28" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" MaxLines="2"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Date, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}" TextColor="White" FontSize="14"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Comments}" TextColor="White" FontSize="14"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.98,1,0.25" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                         Margin="20" WidthRequest="350">
                <Button Text="Bearbeiten" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" CornerRadius="15" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"
                        Command="{Binding EditCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" BorderWidth="3" BorderColor="Yellow" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
                <Button Text="Löschen" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" CornerRadius="15" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"
                        Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </Border>
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: you are passing a reference to an object to another page and then making changes to that same object.  If you don't want this behavior, then the Edit page needs to make a **copy** of that object before editing it, and then apply any changes to the copy back to the reference object

Comment: This is standard c# behavior for an instance of a class. Unless you make a new instance (a copy) as Jason says, you are directly editing the `item` that was passed in.

Comment: Thank you both of you. I thought that passing the object to another page would sort of get rid of the reference to the original object. I did change my code to serialize the object first and then pass it on and now everything works fine. Thanks!